# Delete files on HDD while using LiveCD

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, filesystem, live-cd

I've got a little problem.

After installing the latest upadates Ubuntu 13.10 (IIRC) and rebooting, I can access the GUI log-in interface, but after entering my password the monitor remains black with the cursor in the middle. I can move it though, but nothing more happens.

Since I knew there was pretty less space available, I think the problem might be that the harddrive is just full and therefore Ubuntu can't be loaded fully. I now made a LiveCD and booted from it. Everything went fine and I can access the HDD and see most of the folders. Here comes the tricky part. If I want to open a folder at one point I get the notification that I don't have the permission to access this folder or file.

The plan was to use the LiveCD to access the files and delete some to free some space and then reboot. Since this isn't working I don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks in advance for your help.

cheers

Update 1:
When I look at ls -l the output of some of the directories which I then can't access is

```
drwx------
```

Comment: Can you run `df -h` to confirm that you are actually running out of space? As for deleting files with the LiveCD, try using `sudo` to remove the directory as root. Run `sudo nautilus` to use Nautilus or `sudo rm` on the command line.

Comment: I used the `df -h` and there is no space available. I used `sudo nautilus` for using it to remove the file. The only option available was "Move to Trash". The file was ~2-5 GB big, but after running `df -h` again, there is no change so far. Thought about using `sudo rm` but can't access the directory in which I want to delete the file.

Comment: @dan08, sorry where can I find the trash? I checked the Trash of the Live System, but nothing appears there. Searched for the trashfolder on the old system as well, but nothing appeared there. Is there another location due to the running Live system? Thanks.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I misread.

Comment: Used `Shift + Del` to delete a file, now it worked and I checked that there is space now available.

Comment: @Nattgew, thanks both of you for helping me. It worked and I could access now my normal system. Thanks again, spared me some trouble.

Comment: @Nattgew would you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Accepting an answer is enough to mark a question as solved. You don't need to add it to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you run `df -h` to confirm that you are actually running out of space?

As for deleting files with the LiveCD, try using `sudo` to remove the directory as root. Run `sudo nautilus` to use Nautilus or `sudo rm` on the command line.

Comment: I just want to note that in case you can't access a directory on the command line, use nautilus and delete the file with `Shift + Del`. If you just move it to trash it disappears, but you don't get any free space on the drive.