# Ubuntu does not boot due to empty memory space

Tags: boot, memory-usage

I was trying to recover some deleted files using `extundelete` as given in this example [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)
But at the middle I got out of empty space message, after I reboot I couldn't access to ubuntu just ask password and then nothing. 
Then I used [Delete files on HDD while using LiveCD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496569/delete-files-on-hdd-while-using-livecd#_=_option) and deleted those recovered files. But still can't access to ubuntu. What is the problem here?

When I ran `sudo lsblk -i /dev/sdx` I got following result
`sdx 8:6 0 31.1G 0 part /media/ubuntu/......`

Comment: paste the result of `sudo lsblk -i /dev/sdX`, where `X` is your device name

Comment: `sda6 8:6 0 31.1G 0 part /media/ubuntu/.....`

Comment: Pls run `sudo lsblk -i /dev/sda` and post in your question

Comment: I added the result to the question. What is wrong here?

Comment: Please add this too `df --total -hl`